# Rails. MySQL. Variable 'sql_mode' can't be set to the value of 'STRICT_ALL_TABLES'

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

In my project I have to connect my Rails app to old MySQL server(v4) with readonly access. I have third-party application there. Unfortunately I cannot change this situation. 
The problem is when I try to connect there I get an exception:

```
ActionController:Variable 'sql_mode' can't be set to the value of 'STRICT_ALL_TABLES'
```

Here is my database.yml file

```
development:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  database: td
  pool: 5
  username: user
  password: password
  host: 10.12.12.12
```

I can connect to this DB with any DB client, but not with Rails app.
How to fix it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Adding

```
strict: false
```

to the connector settings in database.yml solved the problem.